# Assorted LEGO and BIONICLE set numbers

Tags: set-identification

Lost many of the LEGO parts in a flood.  I've put parts together using best guess so some pictures may represent more than one.

1.

[image]

2.

[image]

3.

[image]

4.

[image]

5.

[image]

6.

[image]

7.

[image]

8.

[image]

9.

[image]

10.

[image]

11.

[image]

12.

[image]

13.

[image]

14.

[image]

15.

[image]

Comment: The black craft in the third picture belongs with the Galaxy Police ship you posted earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1: 8939

2: 7622

3: 5974

4: 7672

5: 8117

6: 8942

7: Definitely not LEGO... not sure what it is.

8: 8016

9: 10134 (NICE!!!)

10: 7262, maybe?

11: 8036 and 7673

12: 7659

13: 8697

14: Possibly 7256. Also 8117

15: 7656 and 7255

Comment: Thanks very much Ryan. #7 turned out to be a Lego Mind Storm Set.  Would have never figured it out without your help1

Comment: Wait, really? I've never seen it before; those parts look very useful if they do fit with regular Technic. Do you know which set?

Comment: They look like a BIONICLE vehicle, maybe a toa speeder from the series directly before Mata Nui's return?